# ansible playbook: pass a parameter as start_time = 10:00:00 UTC

Tags: ansible

How to pass this kind of values in ansible as parameters

```
--extra-vars "start_time = 10:00:00 UTC End_time = 12:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat `-e` (`--extra_vars`) few times, once for each new variable.

```
-e "start_time=10:00:00 UTC"  -e "End_time=12:00:00 UTC"
```